# How Email Agent Works?

Tags: apex, email

We have a scenario where we would like to know that how the Salesforce works, if we are installing an Email Agent behind the firewall at our client site to create an Email To Case for us.

Does that internally uses our Inbound Email Service that we have created to create a case or if it create a case for us using the Soap web service directly.

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Email to Case agent uses the SOAP Partner API, calling a function called "handleEmailMessage". This is a function that simply accepts messages and processes them on the Salesforce server. It does not invoke any inbound email handlers, instead going directly through the API. You can actually see the source code for the agent; it's in the ZIP file. This SOAP API function checks if Email to Case is enabled and throws an exception if it is not active for that organization. Unlike an inbound email handler, this SOAP function call can handle attachments larger than 10 MB, and has several differences as noted in the Help section for the Email to Case Agent. Also, unlike the inbound email service, it can only create cases and add emails to cases, and cannot handle other types of data (e.g. creating a custom object, etc). Inbound email services and Email to Case also have separate governor limits, noted in their respective sections.